# SQL - Return Row Even If LEFT JOIN Fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query with a few JOINS that return data from multiple tables

```
SELECT A.ItemID, A.Title, A.PictureURL as Image, SUM(B.AmountPaid) as revenue, COUNT(*) AS numOrders, B.CheckoutStatus_LastModifiedTime, C.HitCount as today, D.HitCount as yesterday 
    FROM ebay_activelistings A 
    LEFT JOIN ebay_orders B ON 
        A.ItemID = B.ItemID 
        AND ( (B.CheckoutStatus_LastModifiedTime >= :start_date 
        AND B.CheckoutStatus_LastModifiedTime < :end_date) OR B.CheckoutStatus_LastModifiedTime IS NULL) 
        AND (B.CheckoutStatus_Status = 'Complete' OR B.CheckoutStatus_Status IS NULL) 
    LEFT JOIN ebay_hitswatches C ON A.ItemID = C.ItemID 
    LEFT JOIN ebay_hitswatches D ON A.ItemID = D.ItemID 
    WHERE 
        A.ListingStatus = 'Active' 
        AND C.Timstamp LIKE :end_date2 
        AND D.Timstamp LIKE :start_date2
        " . (count($listingIds) > 0 ? 'AND A.ItemID IN ('.implode(',', $listingIds).')' : '') . "
    GROUP BY A.ItemID
```

This query works fine and will only return a row from the "ebay_activelistings" table if a matching "ItemID" is found within the "ebay_orders" table.

However, i want to return a row no matter what, even if there is no matching "ItemID" within "ebay_orders" then the "B." data can be left empty but i still get a row with the other data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Move right side table conditions from WHERE to ON. (Use AND.)

Comment: Could you explain more?

Comment: Make your where clause look like ` WHERE (A is null OR A.ListingStatus = 'Active') AND (C is null OR C.Timstamp LIKE :end_date2) AND (D is null OR D.Timstamp LIKE :start_date2" . (count($listingIds) > 0 ? 'AND A.ItemID IN ('.implode(',', $listingIds).')' : '')) . "`

Comment: If i understood well you just need to change to RIGHT JOIN, it'll take all data from table on the left and if found match it'll add it if not fields will be left to null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used a LEFT JOIN to keep rows from A even though they don't have corresponding elements in B or C or D.

However, if you have conditions in your WHERE clause that relate to B or C or D then those rows will drop out of your answer.

Putting the conditions relating B or C or D in the JOIN condition keeps these in your final answer.

Short answer - move WHERE conditions into the JOIN conditions.

```
SELECT A.ItemID, A.Title, A.PictureURL as Image, SUM(B.AmountPaid) as revenue, COUNT(*) AS numOrders, B.CheckoutStatus_LastModifiedTime, C.HitCount as today, D.HitCount as yesterday 
    FROM ebay_activelistings A 
    LEFT JOIN ebay_orders B ON 
        A.ItemID = B.ItemID 
        AND ( (B.CheckoutStatus_LastModifiedTime >= :start_date 
        AND B.CheckoutStatus_LastModifiedTime < :end_date) OR B.CheckoutStatus_LastModifiedTime IS NULL) 
        AND (B.CheckoutStatus_Status = 'Complete' OR B.CheckoutStatus_Status IS NULL) 
    LEFT JOIN ebay_hitswatches C ON A.ItemID = C.ItemID AND C.Timstamp LIKE :end_date2 
    LEFT JOIN ebay_hitswatches D ON A.ItemID = D.ItemID AND D.Timstamp LIKE :start_date2
    WHERE 
        A.ListingStatus = 'Active' $itemClause
    GROUP BY A.ItemID
```

But... in your php set up $itemClause as follows - this will either be blank or will include the list of numbers.

```
$itemClause = count($listingIds) > 0 ? ' AND A.ItemID IN ('.implode(',', $listingIds).')' : '';
```

Comment: Where would i put the ('.implode(',', $listingIds).' etc?

Comment: I can't understand what that bit does - it is in double quotes so it can't work the way you've shown it

Comment: The ebay_activelistings table has thousands of records, in this instance i am only working with a few of them based on the "ItemID" found within the $listingIds array

Comment: So... if you don't want the row to show at all you can put the conditions in the WHERE clause

Comment: I do want them to show, say for example i am working with 10 rows from ebay_activelistings (ItemIDs are in $listingsId), only 7 of those rows have matching "ItemID" in ebay_orders table, my current query would only return 7 rows and leave out the other 3 as no match found within ebay_orders, i want these rows though also, can be blank (ebay_orders) data for non matches and just show the (ebay_activelistings) data

Comment: I have moved the WHERE clauses into there respective JOIN conditions, just can't get the "implode() etc part to work with it"

Comment: OK - I think I understand - updating answer - I hadn't realised that was php code...

Comment: That PHP line works in the same way as i already have it, problem is, leaving that line within the WHERE clause is still not returning "non table B matches"

Comment: That's odd - are you absolutely certain that those rows exist in A?

Comment: Yes have double checked to make sure, all ItemIDs within the $listingIds array are all within table A

Comment: Sorry Brendan - I'm stumped unless the missing rows in A do not have status 'Active'

Comment: Waw that was it, can't believe i missed that. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand fully the behaviour of your request and what you expect as the result.

In your case those conditions could be too restrictive :

```
AND C.Timstamp LIKE :end_date2 
AND D.Timstamp LIKE :start_date2
```

Maybe try

```
AND (C.Timstamp IS NULL OR C.Timstamp LIKE :end_date2 )
AND (D.Timstamp IS NULL OR LIKE :start_date2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of an outer join working this way:

When no matching row is found, then a dummy row is generated to serve in place of the matching row. That dummy row consists entirely of NULL values.

When we get to the WHERE clause, any condition that requires a column from the outer joined table to be non-NULL will exclude the generated dummy row. And that effectively negates the "outerness" of the join, rendering it equivalent to an inner join.

---

To relate that specifically to the query in the question: this condition in the WHERE clause:

```
 C.Timstamp LIKE :end_date2
```

requires `Timstamp` from the outer joined table `C` to be non-NULL.

This condition evaluates to NULL for any row that has a NULL value for `C.Timstamp`. Since the condition does not evaluate to TRUE, the row will be excluded. That's the reason for the behavior we observe.

---

The fix is to remove the requirement that `C.Timstamp` be non-NULL.

The usual pattern is to remove the condition from the WHERE clause, and relocate to the `ON` clause of the join, e.g.

```
   LEFT
   JOIN ebay_hitswatches C
     ON C.ItemID = A.ItemID
    AND C.Timstamp LIKE :end_date2
  WHERE ...
```

Comment: Yes i have moved them to there respective JOIN conditions so my WHERE clause now only contains A.ListingStatus = 'Active' 
   AND A.ItemID IN (".implode(',', $listingIds)."). This however still only returns 3 rows, when i have 5 ItemIDs within the $listingsIds array.

Comment: @BrendanMullan:  The "missing rows"  behavior suggests several possibilities: `ListingStatus` is either NULL or not equal to 'Active' for the rows with itemId values in $listingIds,  or those itemId values don't exist in the table, or there are duplicate values in the list. But without sample data, I'm just guessing. (i'd suggest an issue with collapsing rows with  GROUP BY, but given that the GROUP BY is on A.itemId, I don't think that's the issue.)

Comment: Yeah turned out to be the ListingStatus, thank you for the help